Christoffel for Poincaré disk in polar coordinates
Using the metric $\frac{4(dr\otimes dr + r^2d\theta\otimes d\theta)}{(1-r^2)^2}$ I am attempting to use the orthonormal frame given by
$$
e_r = \frac{1}{2}(1-r^2)\partial_r,\ e_\theta=\frac{1}{2r}(1-r^2)\partial_\theta.
$$
I found the connection form to be $\omega_\theta^r=-\frac{1+r^2}{1-r^2}d\theta$ and I'm attempting to compute the Christoffel symbols. For a smooth vector field $X$, I think we can write the connection acting on $\partial_r$ as
$$
\nabla_X\partial_r = \nabla_X\left(\frac{2}{1-r^2}e_r\right)= d\left(\frac{2}{1-r^2}\right)(X)e_r + \frac{2}{1-r^2}\nabla_X e_r = \frac{4r}{(1-r^2)^2} dr(X) e_r + \frac{2}{1-r^2}\omega_r^\theta(X)e_\theta = \frac{2r}{1-r^2} Xr\partial_r + \frac{1+r^2}{r(1-r^2)}X\theta\partial_\theta.
$$
However, I believe this results in Christoffel symbols of $\Gamma_{rr}^r=\frac{2r}{1-r^2}$ and $\Gamma_{\theta r}^\theta=\frac{1+r^2}{r(1-r^2)}$ instead of what ChatGPT thinks should just be $\frac{r}{1-r^2}$ and $\frac{1}{r}$, though it derives them using a different method by means of Metric components. Who is right? For reference, here is ChatGPT's method:


The Christoffel symbols depend on what frame is used. You used an orthonormal frame $(e_r,e_\theta)$. You asked ChatGPT to use coordinates, so it used the frame $(\partial_r, \partial_\theta)$. I suggest not using ChatGPT. Or, if you do, don't just compare the final answers. Try to understand what it did line by line and why it looks different from your calculation.

@Deane oh I see! I didn't think about that it would be frame dependent, because I'm using this to derive the geodesic equations which should be independent but that makes sense now. I remember reading your quotation in the New Yorker a bunch of years ago about Yitang Zhang, and appreciate hearing your advice.

OMG, chatGPT again. Better: the package sympy.diffgeom in python. Link.
